# join ordered items from multiple lists together to form new list of concatenated strings

Tags: python-3.x, list, join, concatenation

I have three lists that I'd like to concatenate such that the same items ordered in each list from each list join into one string.

For example,
I have a list of days, a list of months, and a list of years I'd like to combine in a new list such that I have one complete date but with '-' between the day-month and month-year.

If day[0] = '15', month[0] = 'Mar' and year[0] = '2012', the date should look like this in the end '15-Mar-2012', etc.

Using a list comprehension does not work as I just have iterations of combined dates for every item in each of the lists. Any help would be appreciated!

```
day = ['15', '09', '25', '03', '04', '05', '17', '14', '23', '20', '06', '19', '15', '04', '16', '22', '25', '08', '12', '18', '25', '15', '04', '24', '17', '13', '17', '18', '03', '23', '30', '22', '23', '16']
month = ['Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Mar', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Jun', 'Oct', 'Jan', 'Apr', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Feb', 'Jun', 'Feb', 'Dec', 'May', 'Feb', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Aug', 'May', 'May', 'Aug', 'May', 'May']
year = ['2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2013', '2013', '2014', '2014', '2011', '2015', '2015', '2011', '2012', '2016', '2011', '2016', '2012', '2016', '2012', '2016']

combined = [i + '-' + j + '-' + k for i in day for j in month for k in year]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the three lists are of the same lengths (which in this example, they are), then you can use the following list comprehension:

```
combined = [day[i] + '-' + month[i] + '-' + year[i] for i in range(len(day))]
```

Which can be expressed as a `for` loop as so:

```
combined = []
for i in range(len(day)):
    combined.append(day[i] + '-' + month[i] + '-' + year[i])
```

This list comprehension utilises the fact that all the lists are the same size, by getting all the matching information for a specific point in a list.

---

Beforehand, your list comprehension could be expressed as so:

```
combined = []
for i in day:
   for j in month:
       for k in year:
           combined.append(i + '-' + j + '-' + k)
```

Which loops through `days` `len(day) * len(month) * len(years)`, which is why you wouldn't have been getting the expected results.

Comment: Your response was very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since your lists are all the same length, you can use `zip` to combine together:

```
>>> ['{}-{}-{}'.format(*t) for t in zip(day,month,year)]
['15-Mar-2012', '09-Apr-2012', '25-Apr-2012', '03-May-2012', '04-Jun-2012', '05-Jun-2012', '17-Jul-2012', '14-Mar-2012', '23-Jul-2012', '20-Aug-2012', '06-Sep-2012', '19-Jun-2012', '15-Oct-2012', '04-Jan-2012', '16-Apr-2012', '22-Oct-2012', '25-Oct-2012', '08-Nov-2012', '12-Feb-2013', '18-Jun-2013', '25-Feb-2014', '15-Dec-2014', '04-May-2011', '24-Feb-2015', '17-Nov-2015', '13-Dec-2011', '17-Apr-2012', '18-Apr-2016', '03-Aug-2011', '23-May-2016', '30-May-2012', '22-Aug-2016', '23-May-2012', '16-May-2016']
```

Comment: I'm really glad you suggested zip. I attempted to zip together the three lists, but was unable to do so successfully. I also had no idea how to include '-' when zipping. Thank you for providing the solution!